# What is the value of n if n is a positive integer?

Tags: permutations, combinations, factorial

Please solve this question I am not sure how to solve this questioned provide me with the solution

> If 
>   $$
> 2 \times {}^n P_2 + 50 = {}^{2n}P_2
> $$
>   where $n$ is a positive integer, then the value of $n$ is ... Options: 7,6,5,4

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: And please post your problem as *text,* not as a link to a screenshot. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $n=5$.

We want to solve $2P(n,2)+50=P(2n,2)$, where $P(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \binom{n}{k}k!$. This is equivalent to solving $$2\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} + 25 = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!2!} \tag{A}$$ I don't see a procedural way  to solve $(A)$(see edit below) to solve this (except possibly using [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)). We first note that assuming $n \ge 2$ allows every expression in the equation, in particular $(n-2)!$ and $(2n-2)!$, to be defined. I would plug in $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...$ etc until I got a solution (though I wouldn't know if it were unique) or just check [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*P%28n%2C2%29%2B50%3DP%282*n%2C2%29). In your case, we luckily have this question to be multiple choice. Just plug in $n=4,5,6,7$ to see which fit. As it turns out, $n=5$ satisfies the equation.

Edit: Oh ok; I can't believe I didn't see this one. Based on Claude Leibovici's answer, the procedural way to do this is to note that

$$\frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = (n)(n-1), \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!} = (2n)(2n-1) \tag{B}$$

Then use $B$ to make $A$ become $C$ as follows:

$$(n)(n-1) + 25 = (n)(2n-1) \tag{C}$$

Finally, use quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Using $P(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$, you need to solve
$$\frac{2 n!}{(n-2)!}-\frac{(2 n)!}{(2 n-2)!}+50=0$$
Just simplify the factorials to get
$$50-n^2=0$$